# Find token's position in an SQL query using JSqlParser

Tags: java, jsqlparser

I'm trying to wrap my head around finding the position (line is enough) of an SQL object (token?) in an SQL query, using JSqlParser.

For example, in the query:

```
SELECT a
FROM table
WHERE a = 1 AND
      b = 2 AND
      c = 3
```

When looking at the expression b = 2, I would like to be able to know that it's in line 4. Or, when looking at the SelectItem "a", I would like to know it's in line 1.

Didn't see anything in the documentation nor in the objects themselves regarding their positions.
If this is not currently possible, can you please suggest a good approach to adding this capability on my own (easiest and quickest in terms of performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a patched version of JSqlParser, you can't. At the moment JSqlParser V1.2-SNAPSHOT does provide you with AST - node information for some specific parsed tokens, but not for all. Using the following code snipped:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSQLParserException {
    String sql = "SELECT a\n"
            + "FROM table\n"
            + "WHERE a = 1 AND\n"
            + "      b = 2 AND\n"
            + "      c = 3";

    SimpleNode node = (SimpleNode) CCJSqlParserUtil.parseAST(sql);

    node.jjtAccept(new CCJSqlParserDefaultVisitor() {
        @Override
        public Object visit(SimpleNode node, Object data) {
            System.out.println(node.toString() + " firstToken=" + node.jjtGetFirstToken().image 
                    + " line=" + node.jjtGetFirstToken().beginLine);
            return super.visit(node, data);
        }
    }, null);
}
```

You can get informations about all saved AST nodes. Exploring the interface of SimpleNode you also the absolute position and range of your token within your source sql string.

This "limitation" comes from JSqlParsers feature driven development and the massive performance impact on generating all AST-Nodes. Additionally some AST nodes are linked with JSQlParsers parse objects like **Column**, **Table**, etc. which is not done automatically using JavaCC but has to be done within the grammar definition.

At first I mentioned a patched JSqlParser. This is indeed very easy to do by modifiing the **pom.xml** and setting

```
<nodeDefaultVoid>true</nodeDefaultVoid>
```

to **false**. Then for all productions AST nodes are generated. But you will see, it results in a huge tree, even for your simple statement.

If you need this information for some specific productions like your **EqualTo** objects, this could be integrated via a feature request for JSqlParser (github).

**Why those two kind of trees?**

There is a difference between the parse tree and the abstract syntax tree in JSqlParser. For objects extended from **ASTNodeAccessImpl** there is a link between those two. The delivered parse tree objects are a more practical approach to the parsed part of your sql. E.g you are able to set a **Table** object into a **Column** object to reference the column from this table. Using a AST approach this would result in constructing more nodes to construct a point, identifier, etc.

The AST nodes have the information you need, the exact position of a token within your original sql text. If you look at a **Function** object, you can use the method **getASTNode** to get the corresponding AST - node to get the exact position within your sql. But as I wrote, this is only implemented for a few parse tree objects. If you need specific one to get this information, I will happily extend JSqlParser for it, but keep in mind, that getting all of these nodes has a huge performance and memory impact.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So this is an entire different tree of position objects? It's actually doesn't make a lot of sense in my use case, as my goal is to track down an object in the parsed statement (using JSqlParser's regular objects) and get their position. For example, if I found a function name Foo in the tree, I would like to also get its position in the raw query. Can you please point me in the right direction, as I would like to avoid parsing a whole new tree of nodes just to get the position (and I also don't understand the relation between the objects and the nodes trees).

Comment: thank you for the information. You mentioned that this capability is currently only implemented for a few parse tree objects. Is there any easy way I can add this capability for any object? I need it for many types (for example: Function, Table, Column, InExpression, EqualTo, ExistsExpression, LikeExpression, StringValue and many more). I understand this may result in a performance hit, but maybe if I could configure which types I need positioning information for, it would be best. Will be glad for some directions on how to implement this even on my own, as it's very important to me.

Comment: Look at the Function object. First the JSqlParser object class has to be extended from ASTNodeAccessImpl and second you have to link it in the grammar using linkAST, like in the Function production.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to have a look at the current implementation - how do I got the v1.2 snapshot in Maven? Also, where should I add the nodeDefaultVoid configuration? Can you give an example please?

Comment: You can change this only if you build jsqlparser by your own. The actual master branch head is 1.2-Snapshot. Look into the  pom.xml. A jar can be referenced at sonatype maven repo.

Comment: I just tried to test it with v1.1 (which is the version I'm currently using), and it seems I have access to perform calls such as: `int line = func.getASTNode().jjtGetFirstToken().beginLine;`. I'm wondering what's the difference between v1.1 and v1.2-snapshot then if I have access to the AST of several object types in v1.1 as well?

Comment: You could use 1.1. But if you want to provide pull requests you should it base on actual head of master.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Just made an attempt to add the AST link to one of the objects and it worked perfectly. One more question - how would you recommend to implement this link for classes that already extend another class (for example, LikeExpression already extends BinaryExpression, so I can't really add ASTNodeAccessImpl into the mix there in a trivial way) - assuming one of my goals is to find the position of LIKE expressions beginning. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just extended the base class from Astnodeaccessimpl. In your case BinaryExpression. Could you provide a pull request with your changes?

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I ended up doing. Just wanted to see if there is a way to do it without extending BinaryExpression, as it will apply to many other conditions that extend it as well (and might impact performance without a real need). Will be on a vacation in the next week and a half, but will provide the pull request once I'm back. Thanks!